# Android: How to pass the data to sub-activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

The main activity includes some variables with set values. I created a sub-activity with the form which has to be filled with the data from main activity so I guess the data have to be passed to the sub-activity when it starts.

Does anyone know how to pass the variable values to the sub-activity from the main activity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use this method in your main activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourMainClass.class);
i.putExtra("key", value);
```

end then in the sub activity get the value with this method, usually in the onCreate event

```
int value = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("key");
```

I hope this hepls.

Answer (score 2):

Will this work in the main activity?

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourMainClass.class);
i.putExtra("key", value);
```

Followed by:

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
```

And can you add multiple "Extras" like or something like this?

```
i.putExtra("key", value1); 
i.putExtra("key2", value2);
i.putExtra("key3", value3);
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work:

activity1.class:

```
Intent i = new Intent(activity1.this,activity2.class);

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("name", "your value need to pass here");

i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

activity2.class:

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();

String name = b.getString("name");

((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(name);
```