# Dynamic Array input

Tags: android

I was wondering how to make a code to let the user input values into a dynamic array, so lets say the first box the user enters 5, this will be the array length, then he enters another 5 numbers for the array, how do I make this dynamic, instead of assuming the array length will always be 5? and what do we use to enter the data, EditText? if so, does the EditText go inside a loop like :

```
  for(i=0;i<arrlength;i++)
  { 
    arr[i] = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtbound);
  }
```

would this be how I retrieve the data from the user? and after the user enters the specified values, in this case 5 values, how do we enter new screen? should I put a :

```
if(i == arrlength) startActivity(i);
```

inside the for loop?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it looks like you want to create a number of different EditText boxes after you enter the initial value.  Let's handle the dynamic array first.  Have you looked at any of the implementations of the Android [List](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html) interface?  An [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) can be used as follows:

```
ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
integer.add(1);
integer.add(2);
```

To pass data into a new activity, please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073114/android-how-to-pass-the-data-to-sub-activities).

Comment: Hey, yeah I know how to pass data to a new activity, and if I use your example above will it only allow for two values in the array?

Comment: @david No, the arraylist will grow as you add elements

Comment: Hey, sorry, I tried to use your code but it wont work, it says that there's misplaced construct(s), could you show me what xml layout you'd use ?

Comment: @david For what?  The ArrayList code is pretty general and does not necessarily apply to a specific layout.  Now, if you want to add a new EditText with each entry, you may need to dynamically add things to the Layout.