# how to display the spinner selected values to text view in another activity

Tags: android, spinner

I have two activities namely *activity1* and *activity2*.

In my *first activity* I have a *spinner* and in my *second activity* I have a *text view(txt1)*.

Here, all I want is that when a *spinner value* is selected, the selected value of that spinner should be displayed in the *text view* in *second activity*.

---

I can display the selected value of the spinner in text view in *same activity* but I don't know how to display in *activity2* with text view...

Kindly pls help...

Answer (score 2):

Try this it will work:

activity1.class:

```
Intent i = new Intent(activity1.this,activity2.class);

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("name", sp.getSelectedItem().toString());

i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

activity2.class:

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();

String name = b.getString("name");

((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the value you want to display through your intent to launch activity2. Look at the answer posted here [Android: How to pass the data to sub-activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073114/android-how-to-pass-the-data-to-sub-activities) on how to do it. It shows you the concept of how to pass a value from one activity to another.

Comment: Can u just send me an example pls.?

Comment: If you click the link, the example is there.